# Swift custom framework Release build includes *.dylibs that I did not include in the project increasing size to 70 MB

Tags: ios, swift, release

Take a look at the image below. This is the folder structure for a custom Swift framework that I'm developing. It includes C/C++/Obj-C files in it.

[image]

For some reason, when I expand the .framework file, I see a 'Frameworks' folder containing frameworks that I did not explicitly add to my custom framework and the Swift build process adds these.

Without the Frameworks folder, framework size = 6 MB

With Frameworks folder, framework size = 77 MB

Where and why are these addition Swift *.dylibs being added to the final framework binary? Is there some build setting that I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: You may have a finger on the issue, but what is NEContextSDK (NumberEight)? If that's the real culprit, we can't help. You need to contact the vendor - that's THEIR issue.

Comment: NEContextSDK is the custom SDK that I'm building.